# Getting actual model instance after aggregating by maximum value (Django)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

Given the following models:

#### Browsers

| id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |

#### Sessions

| id | last_activity | browser |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 | 1 |
| 2 | 2021-01-02 | 1 |
| 3 | 2021-01-03 | 2 |
| 4 | 2021-01-04 | 2 |
| 5 | 2021-01-05 | 3 |

I want to select the `Session` object with the latest `last_activity` for each unique `Browser`, which in this example will be:

#### Sessions

| id |
| --- |
| 2 |
| 4 |
| 5 |

I've tried `Session.objects.values('browser').annotate(Max('last_activity'))`, but this does not give the actual `Session` instance. Is this possible in Django?

I would like to avoid raw SQL if possible, and avoid looping over a queryset.

Note: This is for an sqlite backend, so `DISTINCT ON` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I found the following solution, which unfortunately uses multiple `SELECT`s

```py
query = Session.objects.filter(browser=OuterRef('pk')).order_by('-last_activity')
query = Browser.objects.annotate(session_id=Subquery(query.values('pk')[:1]))
query = Session.objects.filter(id__in=query.values('session_id'))
print(query)
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand well your question

```py
latest_browser = Session.objects.order_by("-last_activity").first().browser
```

to get each last session per browser:

```py
latest_sessions = []
for browser in Browser.objects.all():
    latest_sessions.append(browser.session_set.order_by("-last_activity").first())
```

or if you want just a query:

```py
id_browsers = Session.objects.values_list('browser', flat=True).annotate(Max('last_activity'))
sessions = Session.objects.filter(browser_id__in=id_browsers)
```

Comment: I want to avoid making multiple queries in a loop. The query solution with `distinct()` doesn't work, all the `sessions` are listed.

Comment: I'm getting `django.db.utils.OperationalError: sub-select returns 2 columns - expected 1`. Also, this doesn't select the selection with the latest `last_activity`, since multiple sessions can have the same browser.